# How can I sanitize user input but keep the content of <pre> tags?

Tags: coldfusion, sanitization

I'm using CKEditor in Markdown format to submit user created content. I would like to sanitize this content from malicious tags, but I would like to keep the formatting that is the result of the markdown parser. I've used two methods that do not work.

**Method one**

```
<!--- Sanitize post content --->
<cfset this.text = HTMLEditFormat(this.text)>
<!--- Apply mark down parser --->
<cfx_markdown textIn="#this.text#" variable="parsedNewBody">
```

**Problem** For some reason `<pre>` and `<blockquote>` are being escaped, and thus I'm unable to use them. Only special characters appear. Other markdown tagging works well, such as bold, italic, etc. Could it be CKEdit does not apply markdown correctly to `<pre>` and `<blockquote>`?

Example: If I were to type `<pre><script>alert("!");</script></pre>` I would get the following: `&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;!&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;`

**Method two**

Same as method one, but reverse the order where the sanitation takes place after the markdown parser has done it's work. This is effectively useless since the sanitation function will escape all the tags, malicious ones or ones created by the markdown parser.

While I want to sanitize malicious content, I do want to keep basic HTML tags and contents of `<pre>` and `<blockquote>` tags!--any ideas how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two important sanitizations that need to be done on user generated content. First, you want to protect your database from SQL injection. You can do this by using stored procedures or the `<cfqueryparam>` tag, without modifying the data.

The other thing you want to do is protect your site from XSS and other content-display based attacks. The way you do this is by sanitizing the content **on display**. It would be fine, technically, to do it before saving, but generally the best practice is to store the highest fidelity data possible and only modify it for display. Either way, I think your problem is that you're doing this sanitization out of order. You should run the Markdown formatter on the content first, **THEN** run it through `HTMLEditFormat()`.

It's also important to note that HTMLEditFormat will not protect you from all attacks, but it's a good start. You'll want to look into implementing [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) utilities, which is not difficult in ColdFusion, as you can directly use the provided Java implementation.

Comment: XMLFormat() is prefered over HTMLEditFormat(); however, the OWASP method is best. You need to be careful of the context the input is rendered within. Jason Dean recently presented at Adobe MAX. The video is available on Adobe TV: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2010-develop/securing-coldfusion-applications You can jump to 12:00 in the video to go straight to the good stuff.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I'm not sure changing the order will work since all the tags from the markdown output will be escaped and the tags will be output as text...

Comment: What I mean is, the tags that I want to keep from the result of the mark down will get escaped. So when I output them, instead of getting the formatting that was part of the mark down, I get the tags ebfore they were escaped. This is why I have the mark-down parser last... as to not sanitized the intended formatting...

Comment: Then it sounds like there may be a problem with your Markdown processor. It should not modify anything inside the `<pre></pre>` block. HTML is supposed to pass through unchanged. One thing that would help would be a clearer explanation of sample input and _EXPECTED_ output vs. _ACTUAL_ output.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just prepend and append pre tag after parsing?

I mean, if you only care about first an dlast pre and you dont have nested pre's or similar. If you cfx tag clears pre, make new wrapper method which is going to check if <pre> exists and if not, add it. Also if you use pre tags I guess new line chars are important, so check what your cfx does with those.

Comment: zarko, not a bad idea, but I'm unsure about the execution... after parsing, I would try to sanitize the the string again, which would leave me with the same result... no?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe `HTMLEditFormat` twin [HTMLCodeFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions-pt0_01.html) is what you need?

Comment: Sergii, what that does is wrap EVERYTHING in <pre> which is not what I'm looking for really :/