# Element Undefined Error In ColdFusion. cfparam does not work

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml, cfimport

I am having problems with my ColdFusion code returning "Element AUTHOR is undefined in FORM." whenever I submit my form.  I've tried using `<cfparam>` to set `comment.author` but it didn't work either.  I'm fairly new to ColdFusion so any reasoning comments would be great too!

```
<cfparam name="form.submitted" default="0" />
<cfset blogPost = EntityLoad('BlogPost',url.id,true) />
<cfif form.submitted>
    <cfset comment = EntityNew('BlogComment') />
    <cfset comment.author = form.author />
    <cfset comment.comment = form.comment />
    <cfset comment.createdDateTime = now() />
    <cfset blogPost.addComment(comment) />
    <cfset EntitySave(blogPost) />
</cfif>

<cfimport taglib="customTags/" prefix="layout" />
<layout:page section="blog">    

        <!-- Content Start -->

        <!--Card  -->
        <div id="content">
            <div class="card-pattern">
                <!-- blog -->
                <div id="blog">
                    <div class="clr">
                        <div class="top-bg1">
                            <div class="top-left">
                                <div><h1>Blog</h1></div>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr">
                            <div class="pat-bottomleft">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="pat-bottomright">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="blog-top">  
                        <div class="clr">
                        <cfoutput>
                            <div class="left">
                                <!-- Blog Title -->
                                <h2 class="big">
                                    #blogPost.title#
                                </h2>
                                <!-- Date Published -->
                                <h5>
                                    <strong>Date Posted</strong>: #dateformat(blogPost.dateposted,'mm/dd/yyyy')#
                                </h5>
                                <!-- Blog Body -->
                                    #blogPost.body#
                                <!-- Blog Export -->
                                <p>
                                    <a href="exportToPDF.html?id=#blogPost.id#" target="_new"><img src="assets/images/export_pdf.png" border="0"/></a>
                                </p>
                                <!-- Blog Comments Section -->
                                <h3>
                                    Comments #arrayLen(blogPost.getComments())#
                                </h3>
                                <div class="clr hline">&nbsp;</div>

                                <div class="clr comments">
                                    <ul>
                                        <!-- Start Comment -->
                                        <cfloop array="#blogPost.getComments()#" index="comment">
                                        <li>
                                            <p>
                                                <strong>Posted On:</strong> #dateFormat(comment.createdDateTime,'mm/dd/yyyy')# at #timeformat(comment.createdDateTime,'short')# By #comment.author#
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                #comment.comment#
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="clr hline">&nbsp;</div>
                                        </li>
                                        </cfloop>
                                        <!-- End Comment -->
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <h3>
                                    Post Comment
                                </h3>
                                <div class="clr hline">&nbsp;</div>

                                <div class="clr postComment">
                                    <form action="BlogPost.cfm?id=#blogPost.id#" method="post" id="form">
                                        <div>
                                            <label>Name <span class="font-11">(required)</span></label>
                                            <input name="contactname" type="text" class="required" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="textarea">
                                            <label>Comment <span class="font-11">(required)</span></label>              
                                            <textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="60" class="required"></textarea>        
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <input id="submitBtn" value="Submit"  name="submit" type="submit" class="submitBtn" />
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </cfoutput>
                            <div class="right" >
                                <h2>Categories</h2>
                                <!-- Blog Specific Categories -->
                                <div id="categories" align="center">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">ColdFusion</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div> <!--blog end -->

</layout:page>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is telling you what is wrong.  There is no *author* element in your form OR there is no *form* scope at all.  Here is the form code that you posted:

```
<form action="BlogPost.cfm?id=#blogPost.id#" method="post" id="form">
    <div>
        <label>Name <span class="font-11">(required)</span></label>
        <input name="contactname" type="text" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="textarea">
        <label>Comment <span class="font-11">(required)</span></label>              
        <textarea name="comment" rows="6" cols="60" class="required"></textarea>        
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="submitBtn" value="Submit"  name="submit" type="submit" class="submitBtn" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
</form>
```

It only contains 4 elements: `contactname`, `comment`, `submit` and `submitted`.  This means that after the form is submitted ColdFusion will have access to:  `form.contactname`, `form.comment`, `form.submit` and `form.submitted`.  I presume that you are trying to set your `comment.author` variable to the `contactname` form field.

You could either change your code where you are setting the variable, like this:

```
<cfset comment.author = form.contactname />
```

Or you could change your code where the form field is defined, like this:

```
<input name="author" type="text" class="required" />
```

Either way, the references to the `form` scope must match the names that you give them in your HTML form.  For what it's worth, you can always dump the `form` scope after it is submitted to see what is available, like this:

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

**Also remember to sanitize all data that you receive from the client.**

[How can I sanitize user input but keep the content of <pre> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173135/how-can-i-sanitize-user-input-but-keep-the-content-of-pre-tags)

Comment: For this particular type of error message, the first paragraph of this answer is not always correct.  Sometimes it means there is no form scope at all.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, undefined because it doesn't exist in the form.

And definitely sanitize all form and url data. One example below:

```
<cfset myVar = ReReplaceNoCase(#FORM.formfield#,"<[^>]*>","","ALL")/>
```